# can anybody help me get rid of this memset?

Tags: c++, memset

here is the Node class , at last line it's been used memset , so i dont wanna 
use it anyway , can some one help me with it ?

```
class Node  { 
    public: 
    int key; 
    Node **front; 
    Node(int, int); 
    }; 

    Node::Node(int key, int level) 
    { 
    this->key = key; 
    front = new Node*[level+1]; 

    // here is memset i wanna remove *******
    memset(front, 0, sizeof(Node*)*(level+1)); 
};
```

Comment: change `front = new Node*[level+1];` to `front = new Node*[level+1]{};`

Comment: Or use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` (which you should do anyway!), then you can provide a default value for new elements when (re)sizing the vector

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is he going to be storing a vector of Node inside Node, or a vector of Node* inside Node? This looks like part of a linked-list implementation.

Comment: Or `std::fill(front, front+level+1, nullptr);`

Comment: @Tzalumen This looks like a tree.

Comment: @eerorika At a second glance I think you are correct. It does still present a similar problem for keeping a vector as storage, and also makes the displayed implementation more confusing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Note that vectors have relatively large memory requirements, which are unnecessary for tree nodes (where the size likely wouldn't change). An alternative option could be `std::unique_ptr<Node*[]>`, which, if created by `std::make_unique<Node*[]>(level+1)`, will be value-initialized to null pointers.

Answer (score 0):

i just wanted a simple replacement with loops

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < level+1; i++)
{
    front[i]=NULL;
}
```

i can use this code above instead